# Logout function throws cannot destructure property 'token' of 'useSelector(...)' as it is null after switching from localstorage to sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This error comes up if I store the user in sessionStorage, but works well with localStorage. It says cannot destructure property 'token' of 'useSelector(...)' here:

Page

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const Page = () => {
const { token } = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);

return (
  <Input value={token} />
)
}
```

Only thing I changed in authSlice is this:

```
const login = async (formData) => {

  if (response.data) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data)); //localStorageStorage.removeItem("user");
  }
  return response.data;
};

const logout = async () => {

  if (response.data) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("user"); //localStorageStorage.removeItem("user");
  }
  return response.data;
  
};
```

When I logout it throws this error. What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it working when you are logged in?

Comment: Yes @LajosArpad

Answer (score 0):

`sessionStorage` stores your data while the session is alive and whenever the session is being destroyed, for example when you log out, everything stored in `sessionStorage` is lost.

[image]

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

So, the behavior you described is expected. As a general rule, if you want to persist some local data in the browser accross sessions, then use `localStorage`. By contrast, if you rather intend your local data to expire along with the session, use `sessionStorage`.